# WildFly content is obsolete and will be removed

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I try to deploy an EAR on an **empty** WildFly server using a script containing this CLI command:

```
deploy path/app.ear --server-groups=myServerGroup
```

However, it seems that WildFly removes the deployment. Indeed, in the `wildfly/domain/log/host-controller.log` file, I see:

```
2017-03-23 18:00:29,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/e1/42b70f3e3e5127f67b742db96d522c4602a779/content
2017-03-23 18:01:42,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 5) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/b3/ea005efe4d3f22d006db850ac1c88b0a470b3a
/content
2017-03-23 18:10:15,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (Host Controller Service Threads - 32) WFLYDR0009: Content /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/e1/42b70f3e3e5127f67b742db96d522c4602a779 is obsolete and will
be removed
2017-03-23 18:10:15,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (Host Controller Service Threads - 32) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/e1/42b70f3e3e5127f67b742db96d522c4602a779
/content
```

Moreover, if I manually run the command, the deployment works.

When does WildFly consider a content as obsolete?
Why my deployment would be considered as obsolete?

**UPDATE**

Another example :

```
2017-05-23 16:06:48,493 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/57/f5a4fe985f3528222053b0404654ead3502fa9/content
2017-05-23 16:13:05,281 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (Host Controller Service Threads - 3) WFLYDR0009: Content /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/57/f5a4fe985f3528222053b0404654ead3502fa9 is obsolete and will be removed
2017-05-23 16:13:05,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (Host Controller Service Threads - 3) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /opt/jboss/wildfly/domain/data/content/57/f5a4fe985f3528222053b0404654ead3502fa9/ content
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue in Wildfly 10.1. Did you get this resolved in the meantime?

Comment: No sorry, my project was canceled

Answer (score 1):

The content is considered obsolete when it is not referenced from a deployment through its hash and if it is more than 10 minutes old.

Comment: you could try to set "org.jboss.as.repository" in TRACE mode to see what happnes (but i'm not sure this is sufficient)

Comment: How long does it take your script to execute ?

Comment: My script just calls the wildfly `deploy` command. In the log, it is written "Content added" but, later "Content obsolete" and "Content removed"'

I updated my question to add an example in which there is only 7 minutes between "added" and "removed"

Comment: What seems strange to me is that there is no trace about deploying the application itself, just about adding the content. I have a proposed fix that might help you, could you try it ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueaurw8jseyvoum/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: I have other server-groups where other apps are correctly deployed, and there is no log of deployment in the file (host-controller.log), just "content added".

What is the fix? I guess it would work, as it always worked in my local default wildfly environment. But my dev and prod environments use the Docker image of WildFly and contain a lot of custom configurations... So it is very hard to find the wrong configuration.

Comment: It could be a race condition on the closing of the server but i can't reproduce it locally. I'm trying to avoid this race issue in the current fix.